# Why getExternalCacheDir() return null?

Tags: android

I am using two devices having internal memory and SD card. But in one device i am getting null value when executing `context.getExternalCacheDir()`.

> What is the reason for that?
>
> Is it possible to make ExternalCacheDir by calling
>   `context.getExternalCacheDir().mkdir();`

Comment: did you give write external storage permission ?

Comment: No. Is it needed in the case of cache? I am developing on Android 6.0 too. So I am not used it.

Comment: oh okay , then you need to add marshmallow condition

Comment: to read external storage and write external storage

Answer (score 2):

The return value description, direct from the [javadoc for Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29):

> the absolute path to application-specific directory. May return null
>   if shared storage is not currently available

Always read the javadoc!  In this case, as other say, you may just lack permission to access it.

Comment: " Starting in KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. "    : is it means below KITKAT need Permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for working on Cache?

Comment: Yes, for more information you could also click through to the permissions links in that javadoc to read more javadoc for the permissions. Read all the links!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission before

Comment: Whilst this is the advice missing from the previous answers, it is not in itself a complete answer. When you want to add to existing answers, leave a comment on that answer, if you want to post your own, especially for old posts it should be a complete referenced response that also points out why this answer is superior to the existing ones, you effectively need to sell it, tell us why we should vote for your answer.